# How to swap the QListWidgetItem in QListWidget by mouse event?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to implement the images icon list that connect to the corresponding image. Now, I want to swap the images icon list to change their index in the list.

How can I swap the icon smoothly?

GIF Bellow:

What I want

[image]

What I have now (with ListWiget)

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.listwidget = QListWidget()
        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.listwidget.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        qPixmap = QPixmap('images/002.jpg')
        self.label.setPixmap(qPixmap)
        image_list_item = QListWidgetItem()
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(qPixmap, QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        image_list_item.setIcon(icon)
        self.listwidget.addItem(image_list_item)

        w = self.listwidget.sizeHintForColumn(0) + 2 * self.listwidget.frameWidth()
        self.listwidget.setFixedSize(w, 512)

        qPixmap = QPixmap('images/003.jpg')
        image_list_item = QListWidgetItem()
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(qPixmap, QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        image_list_item.setIcon(icon)
        self.listwidget.addItem(image_list_item)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to set [ViewMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) and [DragDropMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#dragDropMode-prop).

Just add these lines below to the `initGUI` method:

```
self.listwidget.setViewMode(QListView.ListMode)
self.listwidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
```